# Dynamic contrasting Text Color

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uicolor

Right now I am working on a project that involves a colorful background and a label in front of the background. The only problem is that the color of the background is random, so I need to have a dynamic text color for the UILabel. Essentially the text color of the label needs to change so it contrasts with the background (for ease of readability). I am not sure how to go about doing this in swift. I was wondering if I could get some help regarding this matter.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You surely tried *something*. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that this does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: Is the text going to basically be white and black?

Comment: @agibson007 yes the text is going to alternate between shades of black and white

Answer (score 1):

How about looking at the brightness value of your colour and then returning black for bright colours, or white otherwise…

```
var contastingTextColour: UIColor {

    var brightness: CGFloat = 0
    getHue(nil, saturation: nil, brightness: &brightness, alpha: nil)

    return brightness < 0.5 ? .white : .black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix a color by dynamically adjusting its brightness while retaining hue, saturation and alpha of the original color. The 0.2/0.8 thresholds can be experimented with and modified to suit your purposes, but here, provide a rough estimate of a bare minimum that will hopefully ensure the color has at least feint visibility.

The use case for the following example code, i.e. checking for the iOS screen light/dark mode, is because the backgrounds used in an app I'm working with are system light/dark mode context-sensitive (e.g. automatically chosen based on phone's light or dark mode user-setting by the OS, such as `UIColor.systemBackground`, `.systemFill`, `.secondarySytemFill`, etc... etc... etc...), and where the foreground color is chosen by the user via the app using a color picker. This compensates for cases where user-chosen colors may not provide enough contrast against system-provided light or dark mode relevant background to be visible, and ensures the color user's foreground is retained but visible..

```
extension UIViewController {
    var isDarkMode: Bool {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

var color : UIColor // Some color you need to fix-up
var h = CGFloat(0), s = CGFloat(0), b = CGFloat(0), a = CGFloat(0)
color.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a)
b = self.isDarkMode ? fmax(b, 0.2) : fmin(b, 0.8)
color = UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: b, alpha: a)
```